# I need to convert any string without GET parameters

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need to convert any string without GET parameters:

www.mysite.com/?a=5&s=5  --->   www.mysite.com/

www.mysite.com/books/?bla=blabla&bla=4   --->   www.mysite.com/books/

I need to hide $_GET parameters.

I cant use POST parameters.

How can i do this ?

Comment: "Hide" how? From the target page? From the user (e.g., in the address bar)? `mod_rewrite` isn't going to change what the user sees for the URL...

Answer (score 0):

Then use POST.

POST-Data is not visible in the url and can be used like GET, but has to be pushed from a HTML-Form or something

Answer (score 0):

Variables submitted by the method `GET` go in the `URL`, so it's impossible to hide them. However, you can make them prettier using the [MVC architectural pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). It's a more sofisticate solution that really pays off, in terms of organization.

For example, URLs like `mysite.com/?a=5&s=5` would become `mysite.com/5/5`

You used `$_GET[]`, so I assume you're using PHP. Take a look at [Laravel](http://laravel.com) or [Phalcon](http://phalconphp.com/).

In case you do not want to show any of the variables, you have to use [POST](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-post.html). Data submitted by `POST` is inserted in the body of the `HTTP` request. Please, keep in mind that the body **will not** be encrypted, unless you use [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure).